# Flutter - Applying theme mode Dark/Light from a boolean variable in Shared preferences using Provider

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, provider

I am using `Provider` to manage the Dark/Light theme across a `Flutter` mobile application and I need to store the theme setting in `Shared Preferences` as a `boolean` currently the theme setting is controlled via a Switch.
I couldn't figure out how to do it and couldn't make my way around Shared Prefs.

Below is my attempt at implementing said feature but couldn't make it work.

**Q: How to implement Shared Prefs and store the theme data inside?**

Switch button widget:

```
class ThemeToggle extends StatelessWidget {
  setThemeModeSP(bool isDark) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('isDarkEnabled', isDark);
  }

  isPresentSP(String prefKey) async {
    SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (sp.containsKey(prefKey)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  removeThemeModeSP() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.remove('isDarkEnabled');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
    return Switch.adaptive(
      value: themeProvider.isDarkMode,
      onChanged: (value) {
          final provider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false);
          provider.toggleTheme(value);
          setThemeModeSP(value);
      });
  }
}
```

Theme provider class

```
class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeMode themeMode = ThemeMode.light;
  bool get isDarkMode => themeMode == ThemeMode.dark;
  void toggleTheme(bool isOn) {
    themeMode = isOn ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**UPDATE: I MANAGED TO STORE A DARK MODE BOOLEAN IN SHARED PREFERENCES BUT WHEN I RETRIEVE IT THE THEME DOES NOT CHANGE**

I tested and found the the boolean value is stored and retrieved successfully the only problem that remains is that **the theme goes back to default when app is restarted**

Here are the changes I made:

Switch button widget:

```
class ThemeToggle extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
    return Switch.adaptive(
      value: themeProvider.isDarkMode,
      onChanged: (value) {
          final provider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false);
          provider.toggleTheme(value);
          mSharedPrefs.setBool('myThemeMode', value);
      });
  }
}
```

Theme provider class

```
  isPresentSP(String prefKey) async {
    SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (sp.containsKey(prefKey)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

Future<bool> fetchThemeSettingsFromSP() async {
    SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    try {
      if (isPresentSP('myThemeMode') == false) {
        return false;
      } else {
        var spr = mSharedPrefs.getBool('myThemeMode');
        if (spr != null) {
          if (spr) {
            return true;
          } else if (!spr) {
            return false;
          }
        } else if (spr == null) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return false;
    } catch (e) {
      print('fetch theme from SP err: ' + e.toString());
      return false;
    }
  }

 themeModeSettings() {
    fetchThemeSettingsFromSP().then((val) {
      if (val == null) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return val;
      }
   });
}

class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeMode themeMode = ThemeMode.light;
  bool get isDarkMode => themeModeSettings() ?? themeMode == ThemeMode.dark;
  void toggleTheme(bool isOn) {
    themeMode = isOn ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in `ThemeToggle` class:

```
class ThemeToggle extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
    return Switch.adaptive(
      value: themeProvider.getThemeBoolSP().toString() == 'false' ? false : true,
      onChanged: (value) async {
          SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          final provider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false);
          provider.toggleTheme(value);
          mSharedPrefs.setBool('myThemeMode', value);
      });
  }
}
```

in `ThemeProvider` class:

```
class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  getThemeBoolSP() async {
    SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return mSharedPrefs.getBool('myThemeMode');
  }

  ThemeMode themeMode = ThemeMode.light;
  bool get isDarkMode => themeMode == ThemeMode.dark;

  void toggleTheme(bool isOn) {
    themeMode = isOn ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

in `main.dart/MyApp` class:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ThemeProvider(),
      builder: (context, _) {
        final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          themeMode: themeProvider.getThemeBoolSP().toString() == 'false' ? ThemeMode.light : ThemeMode.dark,
          theme: UIThemes.lightTheme,
          darkTheme: UIThemes.darkTheme,
          home: Newsfeed(),
        );
      });
}
```